# Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//)

Tags: perl

I'm getting this error even though I have declared my regex variable.

`my $pattern = '(Cat\.\sNo\.\s\d+)';`

Later in my code I use then `$pattern`.

```
if ($page =~ /$pattern/)
{
  push(@array, $element);
}
```

But when I run my code it gives me the below error, and continues to run successfully:

```
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//)
```

A search on Google for this error seems to point to scenarios where the variable has not been initialised, although in my case it would seem I have initialised it already?

Comment: Could you show us more code? Where are `$page` and `$element` defined? I suspect a variable scope problem.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That message is not telling you that `$pattern` is uninitialized; it's telling you that `$page` is uninitialized. If you're expecting that `$page` might be uninitialized, and that's O.K., then you can bypass the warning, and make things clear for future readers of the source-code, by writing this:

```
if (defined($page) && ($page =~ /$pattern/))
```

Comment: Ok I've updated the code in the original question.. So in this case both `$page` and `$element` have been previously initialised with `my $page` and `my $element`. Yet I still get the uninitialised error?

Comment: Just another note, I initialised $page and $element with default blank values, i.e. ""

Comment: `my $page` doesn't *initialize* `$page`, it merely *declares* it. `my $page;` is equivalent to `my $page = undef;`, and is *not* equivalent to `my $page = '';`. Right before your `if` statement, if you add the statement `if(defined $page) { print "\$page is initialized\n"; } else { print "\$page is uninitialized\n"; }`, what does it print?

Comment: Thanks ruakh, from that I could determine where it was not initialising $page - as sometimes the var was initialised but other times it obviously didn't initialise. Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't `$pattern` - the problem is `$element`

A quick test will produce the same result:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $pattern = '(Cat\.\sNo\.\s\d+)';
my $element =~ /$pattern/;
```